# Cannot read property 'lineWidth' of undefined , chat type is columnrange highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

i am getting Cannot read property 'lineWidth' of undefined, when using columnrange chart highcharts, this chart i am trying in reactJS
Below is the sample code

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
// import ReactHighstock from 'react-highstock';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts-more';
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts-exporting';

export default class MainChartRange extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            type:"column"
        })
    }
    componentDidMount(){

        setTimeout(function(e){
            HighchartsMore(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
            HighchartsExporting(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
        },5000);

    }   
  render() {
        HighchartsMore(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
        HighchartsExporting(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
        var config = {

        chart: {
          type: 'columnrange',
          inverted: true
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        subTitle: {
          text: null
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            pointWidth: 30
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            pointWidth: 30
          }
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Woring time'],
          title: {
            text: null
          },
          gridLineWidth: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
            },
        series: [{
          data: [
                    [1,1483337940000,1483337950000],
                    [1,1483337970000,1483337990000],
                    [0,1483338000000,1483338010000],
                    [0,1483338030000,1483338070000]
                ]
        }]

     }
    return (
      <div className="graph-container">
        <ReactHighcharts config={ config } style={{"min-width": "310px", "height": "400px", "margin": "0 auto"}}>
        </ReactHighcharts>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

this sample code working for the other chart types but it is giving an error for "columnrange" 
highcharts.js:299 -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lineWidth' of undefined

Please help me find some work around for the "columnrange"

Comment: Could you please post minimal example of your issue? And post the code you are using for making your chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is workaround that is got above columnrange to work

in render function add the below code

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.pointAttribs = function (point, state) {
        var seriesMarkerOptions = this.options.marker,
                    seriesStateOptions,
                    pointOptions = point && point.options,
                    pointMarkerOptions = (pointOptions && pointOptions.marker) || {},
                    pointStateOptions,
                    strokeWidth = 1,
                    color = this.color,
                    pointColorOption = pointOptions && pointOptions.color,
                    pointColor = point && point.color,
                    zoneColor,
                    fill,
                    stroke,
                    zone;
                if (point && this.zones.length) {
                    zone = point.getZone();
                    if (zone && zone.color) {
                        zoneColor = zone.color;
                    }
                }

                color = pointColorOption || zoneColor || pointColor || color;
                fill = pointMarkerOptions.fillColor || point.color || color ;
                stroke = pointMarkerOptions.lineColor || point.color || color;

                /*// Handle hover and select states
                if (state) {
                    seriesStateOptions = seriesMarkerOptions.states[state];
                    pointStateOptions = (pointMarkerOptions.states && pointMarkerOptions.states[state]) || {};
                    strokeWidth = pointStateOptions.lineWidth || seriesStateOptions.lineWidth || strokeWidth + seriesStateOptions.lineWidthPlus;
                    fill = pointStateOptions.fillColor || seriesStateOptions.fillColor || fill;
                    stroke = pointStateOptions.lineColor || seriesStateOptions.lineColor || stroke;
                }*/

                return {
                    'stroke': stroke,
                    'stroke-width': strokeWidth,
                    'fill': fill
                };

    };
    HighchartsMore(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
    HighchartsExporting(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and was able to solve it by explicitly providing 'marker' configuration with labelWidth value in plotOptions object of my chart config.

Following is a sample chart config that I have tested both in my application using react-highcharts as well as using locally running instance of react-highcharts demo:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 400
  },
  xAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    plotLines: [{
      color: '#303030',
      width: 2,
      value: 67,
      zIndex: 5
    }, {
      color: '#303030',
      width: 2,
      value: 77.5,
      zIndex: 5
    }]
  },
  plotOptions: {
    columnrange: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter() {
          return `${this.y}°F`;
        }
      },
      marker: {
        enabled: false,
        lineWidth: 0
      },
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'columnrange',
    color: '#4AA013',
    data: [
      [70, 75]
    ]
  }]
```

Note: I did not have to make any code changes to highcharts or modify its implementation like previous answer (which did not work for me when tested using react-highcharts).